# Why do I need parenthesis In bash `set -e` and negated return code

Tags: linux, bash, shell, xargs

I have a shell script which checks for windows line endings.

```
set -e
(! git ls-files | xargs grep -I $'\r')
```

I am using the `!` character to negate the return code of the command.  Grep will return code `0` when a file with carriage return is found, and `!` negates the value to the return code is then `1` and the script exits.  When used with `grep` (no `xargs`) this works without parentheses. When `xargs` is used the negation takes place according to `$?`, as `echo $?` will print `1`, however the script does not exit! After adding parentheses around the whole command, it works as expected. Why are the parentheses needed?

Comment: "*When used with grep (no xargs) this works without parentheses.*" This is a little unclear. Will you please show the code?

Comment: _"the script does not exit"_ is also unclear.

Comment: [`set -e` is full of gotchas](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105), to the point where the bash community is very much split on whether it's a good idea at all.

Comment: ...it would be much clearer to write your code as `git ls-files | xargs grep -I $'\r' && exit 1`, which makes your intent to terminate the script completely explicit -- both in terms of no longer being dependent on `set -e` (which changes behavior wildly between shell releases), and in terms of being obvious to the reader.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with `xargs`.

The `-e` option of bash is a little tricky.

> **-e**      Exit immediately if a *pipeline* (which may consist of a
>             single *simple command*), a *list*, or a *compound command*
>             ,  exits with a non-zero
>             status.  **The shell does not exit** if the command that
>             fails is part of the command list immediately
>             following a `while` or `until` keyword, part of the test
>             following the `if` or `elif` reserved words, part of any
>             command executed in a `&&` or `||` list except the command
>             following the final `&&` or `||`, any command in a
>             pipeline but the last, or **if the command's return
>             value is being inverted with `!`**.

Let's look at a much simpler example:

```
$ cat exit_on_error_test.sh 
#!/bin/bash

trap 'echo Interrupted because of an error' ERR
set -e

! true
echo Exit status: $?

$ ./exit_on_error_test.sh 
Exit status: 1
$
```

So, even though the exit status of "`! true`" was non-zero, the script was allowed to run to the end and output the value of the exit status. That's because we didn't have any failing command - the non-zero exit code was due to deliberate negation.

However, if we enclose "`! true`" in parentheses we introduce a failing (compound) command.

```
$ cat exit_on_error_test.sh 
#!/bin/bash

trap 'echo Interrupted because of an error' ERR
set -e

(! true) # This as a whole is now a failing (compound) command
echo Exit status: $?

$ ./exit_on_error_test.sh 
Interrupted because of an error
$
```

Answer (score 1):

The `set -e` command instructs to

> Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status

(see `help set`).

In Bash, an expression in parentheses creates a [subshell](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html) (subprocess), which works like a single command. Thus, if a subshell exits with an error code, the parent script exits, too (due to the `-e` setting).

So if `grep` finds the `\r` character, the subshell exits with non-zero status; the main script exits with this code, too (due to `set -e`).

The answer to your question *Why are the parentheses needed?* is: because you probably want to exit the main script, if `grep` finds a `\r` character in one of the files under git control.